# Have someone ever seen those Interface Builder properties 'Opaque' and 'Clears Graphics Context' work?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uibutton

I am scanning my whole project disabling anything that can be disabled to speed the application. For example, the user interaction property of views that don't need to respond to touches and things like that. I know the gain will be minimum but anyway, allow me to do that.

Looking at what stuff I can turn OFF, I see these properties called `Opaque` and `Clears Graphics Context`, that I know for a long time, on all views.

I develop for iOS since 2008, initially creating everything programmatically and extensively using Interface Builder since the storyboards were created.

Said that, I have realized that I never saw these properties `Opaque` or `Clears Graphics Context` produce any difference at all, despite their states.

For example: I have created this `UIButton` now that uses a background image. The image has a semi opaque shadow. I set the button's `Opaque` and `Clears Graphics Context` properties on/off and there is no difference on Interface Builder and no difference when the app runs.

I know what Apple say these properties in theory but thinking about them now, I realize that I never saw any of them produce any difference at all, despite their state, even when I used to create views programmatically.

Can you guys give some example of codes where the status of these properties will make an effect?

Comment: `opaque` views are quicker to draw as no compositing is required. This makes little difference for static views but on tableviews/scrollviews/collectionviews or in animation where views must "move" this can be the difference between 60fps and poor performance. Apple have covered this topic in past free WWDC videos on performance. `UIVisualEffectViews`, which are transparent AND blur the background, can cause a big performance hit, for instance.

Comment: >This makes little difference for static views ... I would say no difference at all. Why don't you make this comment your answer, so I can accept?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer but I'm afraid I don't have any info about `Clears Graphics Context`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`opaque` views are quicker to draw as no compositing is required. This makes little difference for static views but on `UITableView`s / `UIScrollView`s / `UICollectionView`s or in animation where views must "move" this can be the difference between 60fps and poor performance.

Apple have covered this topic in past free WWDC videos on performance. UIVisualEffectViews, which are transparent AND blur the background, can cause a big performance hit, for instance.

Below are links to free WWDC videos that reference graphics / UI performance; there are definitely more WWDC `CAAnimation` / `SpriteKit`  videos but the ones below specifically cover performance.

WWDC 2012:

- Optimizing 2D Graphics and Animation Performance: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/506/ (talks about `opaque`; includes example of using instruments to debug an app for better performance)
- iOS App Performance: Graphics and Animations: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/238/ (smooth animations and scrolling)

WWDC 2014:

- Advanced Graphics and Animations for iOS Apps: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/419/ (UIVisualEffects; includes example of using instruments to debug an app for better performance)

Comment: T H A N K S ! ! !